# How to slipt a date which is already stored in a database using php

Tags: php, date

I created a database table using mysql.there I stored date using date picker.If I want to assign that stored date to three variables called $year ,$month and $day ,how can I take that values separately using php?

```
table name   ---->VehicleMeter
table fields ----> Date , Vehicle_no ,meter,status
queries      ----> 
$Selectdate=mysql_query("Select date from `VehicleMeter` where status='1'");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($Selectdate);
$date=$r['date'];
```

If the out put of the variable named $date is 2006-08-21

I want assign that in to separate three variables.such as for $year variable should be 2006,$month should be 08 and $day should be 21.how can I do this?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your `$date`, and use [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), like:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
echo $year."<br />".$month."<br />".$day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

PHP has date function to get all things separately like this,

```
$date = date('d', strtotime($r['date']));
$month = date('m', strtotime($r['date']));
$year = date('Y', strtotime($r['date']));
```

You can also get different 
formats of date like 1, 01 
formats of month like 1, 01, Jan, january 
formats of year like 14, 2014 
from this function.

You can explore idea on DATE from [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var s = myday+'/'+mymonth+'/'+myyear;
var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);
```

Hope you get required output.